# Преобразование больших букв в маленькие на Си

Tags: c

Я должен ввести большие буквы, а программа должна вывести маленькие.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23618316/4928642

Comment: В некоторых компиляторах есть функция `strlwr`, но [не в gcc](https://ideone.com/fY6r5A)

Answer (score 1):

Вы хотя-бы [гуглили](http://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%A1%D0%B8_%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80) ?

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main ()
{
  int c;
  while ((c = getchar ()) != EOF) {
    if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') {
      c += 'A' - 'a';
    }
    putchar (c);
  }
  assert (! ferror (stdin));

  return 0;
}
```

ЗЫ: Специально привожу про верхний регистр, сделайте по аналогии в нижний регистр :)

Answer (score 0):

Смотри в сторону

```
#include <ctypes.h>
int tolower (int);
```